# Proving a function is a Bijection from a set to its complement power set

Tags: functions, logic

I want to prove in elegant way that the below function is a bijection:

$ f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})\backslash A \space; f(a) = \mathbb{N}\backslash a \space $for each$ \space a \in A;A$ is the set of all finite subsets of the natural numbers and the codomain is the complement of $A$ in the power field of the natural numbers

However, in the surjection attempt Im struggling to find the right domain to fit the co-domain. Maybe my initial assumption that the function is bijection is wrong? if so, why?

Comment: The definition of $f$ is unclear. If $f : A \to \ldots$, then $f$ acts on elements of $A$. So, its definition should be sth like $f(a)=\ldots,$ for $a\in A$.

Comment: Are you sure that the function is well defined?

Comment: @Guillerminho77 Hi! yes im sure its well defined, taking any A i can find one of the subsets of its complement to be the image of A. But, im not sure if this is the right thinking.

Comment: I don't understand how this function is defined.  What is its domain?  What is its codomain?

Comment: @lulu Domain is arbitrary non empty subset of N. For example: taking A = {0,1} to be the domain, the codomain is: empty set, {0} , {1}, {2}, ... , {0, 2}, {0, 3}, ....

Comment: A function can not have an "arbitrary" domain.  I think, but am not at all sure, that you mean to say that the domain is the set of all finite subsets of the natural numbers.  And I have no guess as to what you mean the codomain to be.

Comment: As it stands, your question makes no sense.  You can't ask whether a function is bijective or not without clearly stating its domain and codomain.  The identity function from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ is (obviously) a bijection, but the function $F: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb R$ defined by $F(n)=n$, isn't.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the point, edited the question. The codomains cardinality is continuum.

Comment: Once again, you have to specify the codomain.  Though, it's worth noting that, as the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable, it can't be in bijection with an uncountable set.  Voting to close the question.

Comment: If $\ A\ $ is the set of all finite subsets of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $, I'm finding it difficult to understand what $\ f(A)=\mathbb{N}\setminus A\ $ means.  Do you mean instead that $\ f(a)=\mathbb{N}\setminus a\ $ for each $\ a\in A\ $? If so, then $\ f\ $ is not surjective.  Its range would be the collection of [*cofinite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness) subsets of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $, which is a *strict* subset of $\ \mathbb{P(\mathbb{N})}\setminus A\ $ (i.e. the collection of *infinite* subsets of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera yes thats exactly what i mean. I edit once again the question to rid of the ambiguity. Thank you for clarifying the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, $\ f\ $ is not bijective. Since $\ A\ $ is countably infinite, but $\ \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus A\ $ is uncountable, then it follows immediately that $\ f\ $ can't be a bijection.

If $\ b\in\Im(f)\ $ then $\ b=\mathbb{N}\setminus\ a\ $ for some $\ a\in A\ $, so $\ \mathbb{N}\setminus b=a\ $ is finite and hence $\ b\ $ is a cofinite subset of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $.

Conversely, if $\ b\ $ is a cofinite subset of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $, then $\ \mathbb{N}\setminus b\ $ is finite, so $\ \mathbb{N}\setminus b\in A\ $ and $\ b=f\big(\mathbb{N}\setminus b\big)\in\Im(f)\ $.

Thus, $\ \Im(f)\ $ is precisely the the collection of cofinite subsets of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $, so if you choose *that* collection as the codomain of $\ f\ $, then it will be bijective.